# How to verify if a symbol-file is compatible with an executable?

Tags: c, gdb, symbols, elf, coredump

I experience problems analyzing a core dump for an ELF executable accompanied by symbol-file.
Without symbols file I see just function name symbols in back trace:

```
Core was generated by `./DSWP.out'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00005614b4dc58fd in ntl_avl3_find ()
[Current thread is 1 (LWP 1344)]
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00005614b4dc58fd in ntl_avl3_find ()
#1  0x00005614b3ed4c03 in qbra_aro_find_route ()
#2  0x00005614b3ed5c70 in qbra_is_aro_lu_route_found ()
#3  0x00005614b3ed71ba in qbra_aro_add_route ()
#4  0x00005614b3f33c9b in qbum_cont_aro_announced ()
#5  0x00005614b3e4fe4f in qbdc_sub_stage_aro_announce ()
#6  0x00005614b3e4e23b in qbdc_do_work_part_3 ()
#7  0x00005614b3e4f4a0 in qbdc_do_work ()
#8  0x00005614b3ef20d3 in qbrm_conn_fsm ()
#9  0x00005614b3f0c282 in qbrm_process_established ()
#10 0x00005614b3df1a60 in qbrm_receive_proc ()
#11 0x00005614b4dfa78d in nbb_dispatch_process ()
#12 0x00005614b4dfc0f5 in nbb_schedule_one ()
#13 0x00005614b4e0effe in nbb_mp_scheduler ()
#14 0x00005614b4e0f0cb in nbb_sched_thread_main_fn ()
#15 0x00007f6284399ed4 in ?? () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#16 0x00007f6283bf5e4f in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

And when I load symbol-file, the stack gets shorter and some symbols disappear:

```
(gdb) symbol-file DSWP.symbols 
Reading symbols from DSWP.symbols...
warning: Unable to find libthread_db matching inferior's thread library, thread debugging will not be available.
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00005614b4dc58fd in ntl_avl3_find (tree=0x4c026e90, key=key@entry=0x7f61717f9ae8, tree_info=0x4c026ea8) at code/comn/ntlavll.c:510
#1  0x00005614b3ed4c03 in qbra_aro_find_route (aro_cb=<optimized out>, dest_prefix=<optimized out>) at code/bgp/qbraaro1.c:1538
#2  0x00007f616001b7c0 in ?? ()
#3  0x00007f61717f9b20 in ?? ()
#4  0x00005614b3ed5c70 in qbra_is_aro_lu_route_found (nlri=0x7f616001b7c0, route_aro_cb=0x7f614c026c78) at code/bgp/qbraaro1.c:2233
```

Is there a way to verify executable and symbol-file are compatible with each other? or to understand what went wrong while creating the symbols file?

Comment: Looking at the `/lib64/` path, I am assuming you run a RedHat-based distro. Did you enable the debug repositories and install `glibc-debuginfo`? You should be able to find `libthreads_db-*` in directory `/usr/lib/debug/lib64/`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I currently don't care about thread debugging, I just need symbol information